# Can't connect in RDP on an Azure VM

Tags: azure, rdp, azure-virtual-network

I am creating a VM on Azure and connect it to an Azure ExpressRoute VNET.

The problem is that I can't connect to the VM via RDP, but it works well if the VM is not on the network.

What can be the cause of this issue, what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen this article?  The connection may need to be configured differently:

Here is the article: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/expressroute-coexist/